# delete function is not working to delete div

Tags: javascript

i have created text filed row in create function . i added delete button in create() function that calls delete when click on button. any help?

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="createDiv" onclick="create()"/>
</body>  

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">

function create()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<table id='e' border><tr><td><input type='text'><button onclick=del(this.value)</button></td></tr></table>";
    //      newDiv.className = 'newClass';
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

}

function del (e) {
    if ('function' === typeof e.remove) {
        return e.remove();
    }
    return e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
```

Comment: removeChild expects an node to be removed, not a string

Comment: `e` is not an event object or DOM element, it's the value of the button, since you are passing `this.value` to `del`.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Btw, `<script>`s outside of `<head>` or `<body>` are invalid - move it into the body.

Comment: @FelipeKM Your edit is invalid. You broke a string across line boundaries, you uncommented a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the row then the code should be something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    function create()
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var rowId = "someId";
        var output = "<table id='e' border><tr id='"+rowId+"'><td ><input type='text'><button onclick=del('"+ rowId +"')>delete</button></td></tr></table>";
        newDiv.innerHTML = output;
        newDiv.className = 'newClass';
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);                          
    }


    function del (id) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }

</script>
```

If so you have done lot of mistake as Barmar Said.

Comment: thanks a lot. tell me few things what is now doing 1) " onclick=del('"+ divId +"') " and why it is written like this ('"+divId+"'), 2)divID = "someID"; newDiv.id = divId;

Comment: I have edited the answer, please have a look, now there is been deleted the row only as you wanted.

Comment: I am passing the 'rowId', the tr which you want to delete

Comment: could you summarise that thing that inside one +rowID+  in  onclick=del('"+ rowId +"'). small explanation is require as it has really build my new concept

Comment: When you click on delete button del function is invoked, In function definition, del gets the string 'someId' as id, which is passed by onclick=del('"+ rowId +"'). The '+' is concatenation operator in javascript. rowId is variable so we have written like this. del('"+ rowId +"'). Hope this helps to you.

Comment: This won't work if you create multiple rows, because they'll each have the same ID. You need to give each one a unique ID.

Comment: Yeah in case of multiple rows, we should give unique ID for each row every time the create() function is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<button onclick=del(this.value)
```

to:

```
<button onclick='del(this)'>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/CpHe2/3/)

Two problems:

1. You were missing the closing `>`.
2. The `del` function expects to receive the element to delete. The value of the element is not appropriate, especially since the button doesn't have a value.

I'm not sure this will do what you really want. This will just remove the button, it won't remove the table row. If you want to remove the whole table, you need to go up several levels of `parentNode` until you reach the `<table>` element.

Also, you should always enclose attribute values in quotes. In this case it works without them, because there are no spaces in the value, but you should get in the habit.

Comment: thanks but i wat to delete the entire row. it is only deleting the button.

Comment: I know. I said that in the answer.

Comment: Read the part of my answer that begins with "I'm not sure this will do what you really want">

Comment: i am trying to delete the entire row not table.

Comment: Then just go up to the `<tr>` node and delete it. Your table only has one row, though. Are you sure you meant to create a new table with every `create()`, and not just to add a row to the table?

Comment: Sad that the most elaborated answers are not accepted and copy&paste solutions are preferred. But that's not news.

Comment: Even worse, the accepted answer is incorrect because of non-unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the quotes and the Button Tag Close tag '>'

```
<button onclick='del(this.value)'></button>
```

Comment: not working. <button value"delet" onclick='del(this.value)'</button>

Comment: You means <button value="delet" onclick='del(this.value)'</button>
don't forget the 'equal' =

Comment: srry i wrote wrong i am doing in this way:<button onclick="del(this)">delete</button> but not working

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code for your button is incorrect. You don't have a closing bracket for the tag, and as there are no delimiters around the `onclick` attribute value, the closing tag will be part of the value, causing a syntax error in the script.

Try like this:

```
newDiv.innerHTML = '<table id="e" border><tr><td><input type="text"><button onclick="del(this.value)"></button></td></tr></table>';
```